# Security Onion Error: Management IP could not be determined during system setup

Tags: security, centos7

I’m encountering an issue during the setup of Security Onion where the management IP could not be determined. The error message advises checking the log at vroot/sosetup.log and verifying the network configuration. I’ve checked the log but am unsure how to proceed with verifying the network configuration.

```
Here are the relevant errors from vroot/sosetup.log:

ERROR: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)
ERROR: Could not determine MAINIP or MIC_IP.
MAINIP=
MNIC_IP=



Reviewed the network configuration settings by turning on the firewall and enabling DHCP on my VirtualBox through the host system

After verifying the network configuration and trying the above steps, I still encounter the same issue during my Security Onion installation. Could someone familiar with Security Onion please advise on how to troubleshoot this issue further? Thank you!
```